# algorithm performance with insufficient input, part 2

Tags: algorithms

In a previous post, I have asked:

Generally speaking, an algorithm takes some inputs and provides some output. I would like to understand how the algorithm performs when the inputs are incomplete for various real-world reasons. Are there any papers on this issue?

As a specific example, suppose

*the seller wants to sell M items
*there are N buyers each has values for the first item, second item, etc
*but buyers may not report the values for low-valued items (let us say the lowest m items) but the seller does not know the details
*the seller wants to sell M items to the buyers who have the highest values

In this situation what algorithm (other than brute-force) will have some guarantee ?

Comment: Thanks for providing further context.  In the future, rather than making a new post with additional information, please revise the original question using the 'edit' button under the question, so we don't have multiple copies of this.  Thank you!

Comment: In any case, your problem is not well-specified yet.  What properties do you want the output (the solution) to have?  What criteria must it satisfy?  What constitutes "correctness"?  And what kind of guarantees do you want to have?  Algorithms problems can't be solved until you can first precisely articulate the problem: you can't work on *how* to compute something until you know exactly *what* you want to compute.

Comment: Yes. So is there any literature that has studied similar questions?